# MessageBodyProvider not found in Test for Custom provider - Manually works

Tags: java, gson, jersey-2.0, jersey-test-framework

I know that the error "MessageBodyProvider" not found for application type question has been asked a lot of time, but my case is a bit different.

The REST works fine when I manually invoke the REST API through Fiddler or in the browser. So there seems to something odd with the test. I can't get my head around this.

```
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class xxxx.observer.Observer, genericType=class xxxxx.observer.Observer.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:248)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:163)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1135)   at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:248)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:163)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1135)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.doWriteEntity(ClientRequest.java:516)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.writeEntity(ClientRequest.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:384)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:282)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:278)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.lambda$invoke$0(JerseyInvocation.java:753)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:229)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:414)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:752)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:445)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:351)
```

I have a [Custom Json Provider (Gson)](https://memorynotfound.com/jaxrs-jersey-gson-serializer-deserializer/) and my  test class:

```
public class AppTest extends JerseyTest {
    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        String directory = "src/test/resources/de/xxxx";

        ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig(GenericExceptionMapper.class, ScenarioProtocolResource.class,
                CloudlistResource.class, GsonJerseyProvider.class, CORSFilter.class, EncodingFilter.class,
                GZipEncoder.class, DeflateEncoder.class);
        Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();

        properties.put("directory", directory);
        resourceConfig.setProperties(properties);

        return resourceConfig;
    }
```

In my test class I simply try do a POST request:

```
Response resp = target("json/proto/observer/add/xxxxx").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(Entity.entity(observer, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only registering the provider on the server side in the `configure()` method. You still need to register it on the client side. You can see in the stacktrace that the problem is occurring on the client side (see `client` in the package names).

You can either just register the provider on the `WebTarget` or you can override `configureClient()` to register it with the `Client`.

```
Response resp = target("json/proto/observer/add/xxxxx")
        .register(GsonJsonProvider.class)
        ...
```

or

```
@Override
public void configureClient(ClientConfig config) {
    config.register(GsonJsonProvider.class);
}
```

Benefit of the latter is that you don't need to keep registering it with the `WebTarget` on each test.